# Assign individual NIC to KVM guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nic

I have a server with 6 NICs installed and is running Ubuntu 12.04LTS. I want to setup 4 guest VMs using kvm. Now I want to assign 2 NICs for the host(1 Public IP and 1 private IP), and 1 NIC each to 4 guest VM(all private IP). How do I do this?

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

I am having trouble with my configuration file shown below:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.109
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.5

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.117
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.118
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth2
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet manual

auto br1
iface br1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.119
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth3
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off

auto eth4
iface eth4 inet manual

auto br2
iface br2 inet static
        address 192.168.1.123
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth4
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off

auto eth5
iface eth5 inet manual

auto br3
iface br3 inet static
        address 192.168.1.124
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth5
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off
```

---

**Update:** I have it working now. The only issue is that the NICs assigned to be used with the guest still gets an IP on the host, output follows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:2b:cb:2b:61:ed  
          inet addr:192.168.1.109  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7a2b:cbff:fe2b:61ed/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26221 (26.2 KB)  TX bytes:17217 (17.2 KB)
          Interrupt:36 Memory:d2000000-d2012800 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:2b:cb:2b:61:ee  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7a2b:cbff:fe2b:61ee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9898 (9.8 KB)  TX bytes:3409 (3.4 KB)
          Interrupt:48 Memory:d4000000-d4012800 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:18:a8:84:80  
          inet6 addr: fe80::210:18ff:fea8:8480/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11309 (11.3 KB)  TX bytes:2523 (2.5 KB)
          Interrupt:47 Memory:da000000-da012800 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:18:a8:84:82  
          inet6 addr: fe80::210:18ff:fea8:8482/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12541 (12.5 KB)  TX bytes:4154 (4.1 KB)
          Interrupt:46 Memory:dc000000-dc012800 

eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:18:a8:84:84  
          inet6 addr: fe80::210:18ff:fea8:8484/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15136 (15.1 KB)  TX bytes:3053 (3.0 KB)
          Interrupt:38 Memory:d6000000-d6012800 

eth5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:18:a8:84:86  
          inet6 addr: fe80::210:18ff:fea8:8486/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14742 (14.7 KB)  TX bytes:2523 (2.5 KB)
          Interrupt:45 Memory:d8000000-d8012800 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:46422 (46.4 KB)  TX bytes:46422 (46.4 KB)

macvtap0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:8d:e7:e6  
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe8d:e7e6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:14074 (14.0 KB)  TX bytes:1553 (1.5 KB)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easiest way to assign NICs to the guest is to leave them unconfigured in the host, and use macvtap passthrough mode for the guest NICs. Mind you, without additional, more complex settings, this will block VM live migration.

Settings:

```
  <devices>
    ...
    <interface type='direct'>
      <source dev='eth0' mode='private'/>
    </interface>
  </devices>
```

Or you can go for a full PCI-passthrough mode (provided you have IOMMU/VT-d):

```
  <devices>
    <interface type='hostdev'>
      <source>
        <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <mac address='52:54:00:6d:90:02'>
    </interface>
  </devices>
```

Comment: PCI-passthrough mode: and provided your VM has suitable driver support for the NIC...