# Assign a dedicated NIC to a KVM guest only

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nic

My host (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) has four NICs. I would like to give one KVM guest (Debian 10) *exclusive* access to one of those NICs.

So I set the guest-NIC to `macvtap` and source mode to `passthrough`. And the network connection works fine, **but**, like the unanswered follow-up on a [similar issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/446658/assign-individual-nic-to-kvm-guest), my guest also sees (and uses) that NIC.

If I `ip link set down` that particular `en`-interface on my host, it goes down for the guest also (kind of makes sense).

Am I doing something wrong? I thought `passthrough` would "give" the NIC to the guest *exclusively*? Is there any way to have a NIC "invisible"/unusable/inaccessible/down for the host but working for the guest?

Comment: You should _actually_ pass through the NIC, not with macvtap.

Comment: @MichaelHampton In virt-manager, in "Network source", I can only select "NAT", "macvtap" (for each enoX interface), or "Specify shared device name". Only after having selected macvtap can I then select a "Source mode": One of "Bridge", "VEPA", "Private", or "Passthrough". What are you saying I should select?

Comment: You should do what was shown in the second part of the answer you linked to. You DO NOT create a virtual NIC.